# Save new ul list order after button click using Jquery ui

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have a ul with several dynamically loaded list items (given by the controller to the view). I'm able to move the list items with the JQuery UI and Ruxable Sortable libraries.

Now I need to save the new list order. I've seen lots of examples with PHP and classic asp.net but I have no experience in them and I really want to focus on razor and C# here. My database is MySQL.

When the user clicks on the submit button all the controller needs to retrieve is the same list but with altered orderpositions. How can I achieve this?

**View**

```
<ul class="list-group sortable" id="forumlist">
    @{
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <li id="li"@Model[i].id class="list-group-item">@Model[i].name</li>    
             }
    }
</ul>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Opslaan</button>
```

So; Is there a way to send the collection of items back to the controller (via HttpPost) with altered index? The Model[i] contains a "orderposition" property which indicates were the item needs to be shown in the list. This is also the property that needs to be adapted.

Comment: as a side remark, it seems illogic to me to use a `UL` if order is important. It would probably be more semantic to use a `OL` with absolutely no further impact. I know, this is nitpicking, but still, this habit most people have to use `UL` in all cases when a `OL` would generally be suited bothers the semantic-nazi me :-)

Comment: Haha you're absolutely right! I apologize to your semantic-nazi part! It's indeed a bad habit to just use UL whenever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I fixed it!**

So just to clarify the process:

- There is a list of items
- They are displayed in a OL as li
- With the JQuery UI sortable methods the list items are draggable
- The user drags the list items
- The user saves the new order of the list items

So what I did was this:

I just load the items into the view.cshtml:

**Controller**:

```
   public ActionResult Items()
    {
        List<item> items= [METHOD that returns the items]();
        return View(items);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model List<Models.Items>
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateItems", "ItemController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "updateitemform" }))
{
    <ol class="list-group sortable" id="itemlist">
        @{
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <li data-order="@Model[i].position" id="@Model[i].Forum_id" class="list-group-item">item

            </li>    
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].Item_id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].position,new { @id = "item"+@Model[i].Item_id })
        }
        }
    </ol>
    <button type="button" id="saveneworderbutton" class="btn btn-info">Save this shit!</button>
}
```

And now the magic: Javascript/jquery!

```
$(document).on("click", "#saveneworderbutton", function () {
        $(".list-group-item").each(function (index) {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#" + "item" + id).val(index);
        });
        $("#updateitemform").submit();
    });
```

I hope this helps people!

Answer (score 0):

Can you send both information? I mean, you can send two lists, one should be the indexes altered, a list like this:

```
{2, 5, 3, 8, 1}
```

Your controller can expect this: `(... , int[] alteredList)`

Well, a better approach can be create a View Model with a property:

```
public int[] alteredList { get; set; }
```

then, you can populate that property in the View, and your controller will be expecting the new Model (that new model is the View Model that you create for this operation)

your controller's action method look like this:

```
public ActionResult [ListActionMethod](NewViewModel listview)
```

and your view should change the line:

```
@model ...NewViewModel
```

Comment: How would I accomplish that? I mean, how can I create a second list and put the new indexes in there. And make sure the controller knows what index goes to what model item.

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, I still cannot figure out what exactly you mean. In the actionresult that gets the POST back it will have the viewmodel which includes a list of items and a list of indexes (ints). But, how can I make populate the indexes list and update them with the indexes of the list items?

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to each li element for example data=<%=i %>
and then access these attribute using $('Your selecter').attr("data")
and check whether it is odd or even